# Download audio file using cUrl where authentication required to get file

Tags: php, curl

> I want to download a audio file from the server.
>
> When I access the url direct on server that asks for a username & password I want to override it through cURL
>
> Basically I want to allow my web users listen songs on my website. I have an authentication of other web to do so. currently users of my website have double check first they login in my website using credentials after that when they click on Play button then they enter again username & password that I am providing them (of the same web from i have authentication).

```
$url="https://example.com/abc.wav";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "userstring:passString");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

Direct URL after entering the username & password allowed me to listen the audio.
now how can I authenticate my web to access that URL by overriding authentication?
I want to download it and as well as play in the background after clicking on button "download" & "Play" respectively.
On the other hand is there any way that I can email that file without downloading or by downloading it
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Can you describe specifically why/how you need to 'override authentication'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use following code for authentication you forgot to set the header

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
$url = "clip.mp3"
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "password");
curl_exec($ch);
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Comment: yes now I am able to login in admin site. how to overcome redirection of url at the end?